# MySQL query for multi select of random results

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I have a query which randomly selects 4 featured properties based on a particular county.

If there are more than 4 featured properties for a particular county the query pulls the 4 correctly... however when there less than 4 in the county... how do i pull the properties in the county (if any found) then randomly include records outside of the county, so that in total 4 results are shown?

Here is an example of my query...

```
SELECT
    `name`,
    `sleeps`,
    `town`,
    `county`,
    `price`,
    FLOOR(1 + RAND() * p.id) AS 'randnum'
FROM
    `properties_featured` AS `f` LEFT JOIN `properties` ON f.code=prop.code,
    (SELECT MAX(t.id) - 1 AS 'id' FROM `properties_featured` AS t) AS p
WHERE prop.status='on' AND `county`='Dorset'
ORDER BY `randnum` LIMIT 4;
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the county match from the `WHERE` clause, and make it part of `ORDER BY`.

```
SELECT
    `name`,
    `sleeps`,
    `town`,
    `county`,
    `price`,
    FLOOR(1 + RAND() * p.id) AS 'randnum'
FROM
    `properties_featured` AS `f` LEFT JOIN `properties` ON f.code=prop.code,
    (SELECT MAX(t.id) - 1 AS 'id' FROM `properties_featured` AS t) AS p
WHERE prop.status='on'
ORDER BY `county` = 'Dorset' DESC, `randnum`
LIMIT 4;
```